# Net::SSH::Perl returns error for specific server

Tags: perl, ssh

The script supposed to run on my server and executing command remotely(over ssh) on a customer server.
The problem is that I don't have exactly the same platform as a customer server to test connectivity over ssh.
It works on my test servers fine but when working in front of customer server it exits with following:

> "Received disconnect message: No pty allocated, pty required with Telnet SSH
>   at /usr/cti/apps/CSPbase/Perl/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SSH/Perl/SSH2.pm line 300"

When executing ssh on command line i front of this server, its working...

```
$ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($ip);
$ssh->login($remoteUser, $remotePass) ;
($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);
```

what could be an issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe during your testing you are used directly and now it is running from some kind of daemon (so  no pty located).

Maybe some Perl module missing/wrong version (Pty.pm)?

Dump out @INC on both machine and check for differences.

Regards,

Comment: The servers from which I execute the script are identical. The problem that I don't have in my system exactly the same platform as a customer server(destination of my script)